# Exponential distribution -- calculating probability that computer works!

Tags: self-study, distributions, exponential-distribution

If $X$ is the number of years a computer works, and it follows an exponential distribution with a $\lambda=3$, what's the probability a computer will work in 8 years?

I'm not sure that I'm going about this the right way and would love to get feedback.

I'm following this formula: $P(X \leq x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$
When plugging in values for $x=8$ and $\lambda=3$, I get $P(X\leq 8 ) = .9999$...; and to get $P(X>8)$ I subtracted this from 1.
Final answer .000000000378

Is this correct? It seems like a very small probability and not sure that I'm going about it the right way. Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: **Caution**: There are two parameterizations of the exponential distribution in common use. The difference between a pdf of $\lambda \exp(-\lambda x)$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda} \exp\left(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)$ could account for why you believe the final answer is too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the approach is right.  I haven't checked your final computations.  Keep in mind that since the rate $\lambda$=3 the mean lifetime is 1/3 years. So lasting 8 years is a very long time and therefore P(X>8) should be very small. Note that 8 years is 24 average lifetimes.

Comment: A mean lifetime of 1/3 years is so unrealistic for most computers that we ought to use common sense (as employed admirably by the OP) and interpret "lambda 3" as being a mean of 3 years.

Comment: We don't know what the OP thought. It was the rate parameter as stated on the question.  I agree that very few computers breakdown in 1/3 of  year.

Comment: Michael, the word "rate" appears nowhere in the question.  I agree that the OP was using "lambda" as if it were a rate--but isn't that error precisely the issue that needs to be addressed, rather than being compounded by repeating it?

Comment: Even if we take $\lambda$=1/3 and the mean lifetime=3 years, 8 years is still 2.67 years and P(X>8) is still small.

Comment: I don't understand what you're referring to.  "Too small" compared to what?  Regardless, between the two competing interpretations of $\lambda$ only one is plausible.

Comment: i meant to say that 8 years is 2.67 mean lifetime years. So the calculated probability is small.  I am just saying that it is a low probability and not comparing it to anything.

Comment: "Low" implies a comparison: it has no absolute meaning.  The value, by the way, is close to 7%.